# Может ли на интерфейс хоста попасть Ethernet фрейм с чужим unicast MAC назначения?

Tags: сеть, tcp-ip, ethernet, mac-address

Возможна ли такая ситуация, когда на конечный узел придет кадр Ethernet с unicast MAC адресом назначения, который не равен MAC адресу интерфейсов хоста?

Comment: Да. В случае если хост подключен к хабу, который вообще не умеет фильтровать по MAC. Или свитч через который идет пакет не знает на какой порт посылать данный MAC, то вышлет пакет на все порты (кроме управляемых свитчей где это поведение можно настраивать).

Comment: Да, и он его отбросит.

Comment: @L.F.C. Не обязательно, если на интерфейсе включен promiscous mode то ничего он не отбросит

Comment: @L.F.C. https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Promiscuous_mode

Comment: @Mike Ещё зеркалирование портов забыл указать.

Comment: @Mike все ответы нашел, спасибо за то что направил в нужное русло )))

Comment: @L.F.C. Многие управляемые L2 позволяют жестко привязать на порт допустимые MAC и запретить прохождение всего остального. И даже RRCP совместимые свитчи (которые 99% людей считают вообще не управляемыми) как минимум позволяют отключить самообучение на порту, после чего ничего лишнее то же не пойдет. А про L3 речи вообще не идет, потому что в этом режиме уже работает маршрутизация, а она по ip адресам, а не по MAC

Comment: Классно что подобный вопрос подняли, и что @Mike разжевал. Увидел пробелы в своей подготовке ) Автор +1

Comment: Коммутатор ретранслирует unicast-пакет на все порты, в том случае, если в его таблице маршрутизации отсутствует запись, соответствующая MAC-адресу пересылаемого пакета.

Такое может наблюдаться, например, при перестроении топологии RSTP-дерева с момента, когда MAC-таблицы коммутаторов очищаются и до момента, пока не завершится период "обучения" коммутаторов.

Ещё один случай - когда память коммутатора, предназначенная для хранения таких записей, истекла (в сети слишком много устройств или MAC-адреса нагенерил кто-то злой). В этом случае  unicast-пакеты тоже полетят на все порты.